# Modifying redirect URL after inserting page in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor

When using `Insert page` in `Experience Editor` you get redirected to the newly created `page/item` (after choosing the template and the item name).

How can I modify this redirect URL so that I can add a custom query string parameter, or even redirect to a completely different item?

*`Sitecore 8.2 Update 5`*

Comment: What are you trying to achieve via the query string?

Answer (score 3):

Experience Editor provides both backend and frontend pipelines, Insert Dialog belongs to the InsertItem client pipeline.
It is possible to change the redirect URL in this way:

1. Go to the core database
2. Duplicate /sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceEditor/Pipelines/InsertItem/Insert item with changeUrl item name:
   [image]
3. Populate both ProcessorFile and ProcessorName fields like you it on the screenshot above
4. Make sure it has the last sort order.
5. create /sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Pipelines/InsertItem/InsertItem.changeUrl.js file with this source code below:

"

```
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js"], function (Sitecore, ExperienceEditor) {
  return {
    priority: 1,
    execute: function (context) {
      //var homeItemId = "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}";
      var selectedItemId = context.currentContext.itemId;
      ExperienceEditor.getPageEditingWindow().location = '/?sc_itemId=' + selectedItemId + '&myParam=myValue'
    }
  };
});
```

6. After creating a new item using Insert Dialog the browser will be redirected in this way:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

As you did not specify the Sitecore version I will assume that you use `Sitecore.NET 9.0.2 (rev. 180604)` or your version uses a similar approach.

1. Open `core` database
2. Find following item `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Page Editor/Edit/Insert`
3. In `Renderings` field there is a button definition, where you will find source of assets (js) and `ID` of the pipeline that will be called once you click the button in EE. Pipeline ID is `{DF6345DC-ACC8-43B4-BC08-DFBF29906505}`
4. Find `{DF6345DC-ACC8-43B4-BC08-DFBF29906505}` item in `core` database.

Now you can extend pipeline by adding new processors or overwriting existing processors if needed. Right now I can see two processors: `openInsertItemDialog` and `insert`.

Code is located here: `site\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\Pipelines\InsertItem\`

**Older versions** (7.5 rev. 150130 **>**)

If you are using an older Sitecore version you might not find steps above applicable. Here are steps for older Sitecore version.

1. Open `core` database
2. Find following item `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Page Editor/Edit/Insert`
3. In `Click` field there is a name of the command that will be executed when you click the button in EE (`webedit:new`)
4. Open config `http://site/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx` and find following string `webedit:new`.
5. Overwrite this command (search for something like this when you decompile source code (`SheerResponse.Eval("scNavigate(\"" + str + "\", 1)");`)

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified which Sitecore version I was running. Question is now updated with that information. However, I tried your "Older versions" and decompiled `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.New`, copied the code to my own project (and changed namespace accordingly), and created a custom config file that points to my `webedit:new` command instead of the built in one (and confirmed that this config file was added by checking that `admin/ShowConfig.aspx` now includes my namespace instead of the original one). However, none of the methods in my class are hit :(

Comment: @GTHvidsten try the first approach. I am not sure when Sitecore has changed the approach. By "older" I meant versions for which the first approach does not apply.

Comment: You assumed Sitecore 9, so I assumed the older would be for me :) I tried the first approach and could find some JS file, which were sort of understandable. I had hoped, though, that there would be some server-side solution so that I could more easily check templates/parents/links/whatever. The only server-side seems to be the handler associated with `webedit:new`, which didn't work. Unless you have some other tricks up your sleeve it would seem like this would is kinda impossible?

Comment: If you examine carefully logic in JS you will find that you can communicate with a server via `ExperienceEditor.PipelinesUtil.generateRequestProcessor`. The first argument is the name of the request (you will find it in the config). You can create your own request type and do whatever you want on the server side. You just have to make sure that you pass enough information via request. I recommend you to investigate existing requests. Good luck

Comment: After more investigation I can finally work out how the ExperienceEditor pipelines work, and I could modify the existing `ExperienceEditor.Insert` request to change which item is returned to ExperienceEditor, which then redirects to this item instead of the newly created item. However, I can see that the JS pipeline calls `response.context.app.refreshOnItem()` which is what ends up doing the actual redirect. This method is not part of any pipelines. Which means I'm not able to add additional info to the query string :(

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what happens if I add more pipelines to `core://sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceEditor/Pipelines/InsertItem/Insert` Are they always executed in the order they are in Sitecore? The `Insert` pipeline is what does the actual redirect, so if a new pipeline is inserted after `Insert, will it ever be hit because of the previous redirect?